# function pointer in typedef struct in c

Tags: c

I have been working on this code and keep coming across a segmentation fault. I am almost positive that it is coming from how I initialized my function point in the OBJ_T type. Here's what I have:

```
typedef struct obj
{
    COLOR_T color;
    int (*intersect)(RAY_T ray, struct obj, VP_T *int_pt, VP_T *normal, double *t);

    union geom
    {
       SPHERE_T sphere;
       PLANE_T plane;
    }geom;

} OBJ_T;
```

This is the line I get the seg fault:

```
if((*(objs[i].intersect))(ray, objs[i], &int_pt, &normal, &t) == 1)
```

Comment: So.. How do you initalize it?

Comment: You can print any of those values (including the func ptr) to check for "obvious badness" (like null pointers) Looks like you should be doing some good old debugging...

Answer (score 0):

if((*(objs[i].intersect))(ray, objs[i], &int_pt, &normal, &t) == 1)

The memory is not allocated for that pointer that time you will get the segmentation fault.

To solve this, fist you have to allocate the memory for the structure member.

int (*intersect)(RAY_T ray, struct obj, VP_T *int_pt, VP_T *normal, double t);